# How to make code coverage from FlexUnit work with Sonar?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, flexunit, flexunit4

#### Situation

I'm trying to get [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) display the code coverage reports generated by [FlexUnit](http://flexunit.org/) from a Maven build job using Flex-Mojos but I'm not having any luck - all I ever get is a frustrating "-".

---

#### Build output

The result is that the dashboard always shows this (the left column):
[image: Sonar project dashboard]
(no, the unit tests don't run for over 90 minutes but rather 16 seconds; don't know what's off here)

The Sonar related console output is this:
[image: Maven console output]
So everything seems to work fine (no file-not-found errors other than the Cobertura one which I can't seem to get rid of in any way, no parse exceptions, etc).

---

#### Build setup

The `pom.xml` used for building the project looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>swc</packaging>
    <name>Bar</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.4M5</version>
            <type>swc</type>
            <scope>external</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flexunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexunit</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0-8</version>
            <classifier>flex</classifier>
            <type>swc</type>
            <scope>external</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/flash</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
                <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.2-beta</version>
                <configuration>
                    <coverage>true</coverage>
                    <debug>false</debug>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                    <omitTraceStatements>true</omitTraceStatements>
                    <verboseStacktraces>false</verboseStacktraces>
                    <defines>
                        <property>
                            <name>CONFIG::BUILD</name>
                            <value>"${project.version}"</value>
                        </property>
                    </defines>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>asdoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/asdoc/tempdita</directory>
                <targetPath>docs</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>ASDoc_Config.xml</exclude>
                    <exclude>overviews.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <sonar.language>flex</sonar.language>
        <sonar.sources>src/main/flash</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.tests>src/test/flash</sonar.tests>
        <sonar.surefire.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I've tried several ways to run Sonar:

1. `dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports` + `mvn clean install` + `mvn sonar:sonar`
2. `dynamicAnalysis=true` + `mvn clean install sonar:sonar -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true`
3. `dynamicAnalysis=true` + `mvn clean install -DskipTests=true` + `mvn sonar:sonar` (<-- doesn't work: for some reason in this scenario the unit tests fail to run with a NullPointerException during execution of Flex-Mojos's `test-run` goal).

---

Is there a way to make displaying the coverage results in the Sonar dashboard work? Do I need additional plugins for that (Emma, Clover, whatever) to get the coverage from the standard Surefire reports to show up? Is there a known issue that prevents this from working? Am I doing something wrong?

---

#### Update

I've tried running Sonar with the Sonar-Runner. Interestingly, the dashboard then completely drops the code coverage widget. Checking the console output of the runner shows that the runner doesn't execute the `FlexSurefireSensor` (which the `sonar:sonar` Maven goal does):

[image: Console output for sonar-runner]

The `sonar-project.properties` file contains:

```
sonar.projectKey=foo:bar
sonar.projectName=Bar
sonar.projectVersion=0.1.0-SNAPSHOT

sonar.language=flex
sources=src/main/flash
tests=src/test/flash

sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
```

I'm running it with `mvn clean install` followed by `sonar-runner`.

Answer (score 2):

To get code coverage, you need to add the following property:

```
<sonar.cobertura.reportPath>target/site/coverage-cobertura/coverage.xml</sonar.cobertura.reportPath>
```

(or whatever the path to your coverage file is).

This is documented on [the plugin home page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Flex+Plugin).

Answer (score 1):

I think the property you are missing in your POM is **sonar.dynamicAnalysis**:

```
<properties>
    ..
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.surefire.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
</properties>
```

The [Flex plugin documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Flex+Plugin) describes how to enable Unit test and code coverage reporting. It also recommends using the Java Runner, but it should be functionally similar to the Maven plugin launcher.

Comment: I've already tried this setting for `sonar.dynamicAnalysis` and run it with `mvn clean install` (to build the projects and run the tests) followed by `mvn sonar:sonar` (to gather the data for the Sonar dashboard). Didn't work, the dashboard still shows: "Code coverage: -". I've left the property out later since I was trying to get Sonar to run the UT and according to the documentation `dynamicAnalysis` defaults to `true`.